# Broke Python on Mac by uninstalling Python wrong, how to get Modules to work again?

Tags: python, macos, twisted, homebrew, zope

I'm trying to use Python with the Twisted framework, and have been struggling to get it running.

I've got some dirt simple python code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.run()
```

Buy when I run `python server.py` I get back:

> ```
>   File "server.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from twisted.internet import reactor   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/__init__.py", line 53, in
> <module>
>     _checkRequirements()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/__init__.py", line 37, in
> _checkRequirements
>     raise ImportError(required + ": no module named zope.interface.") ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later: no module
> named zope.interface.
> ```

My first assumption was to run `pip install zope.interface`

Unfortunately, all I get from this is:

> ```
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
> zope.interface in
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools
> in
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
> (from zope.interface)
> ```

I also tried `easy_install zope.interface`

But that yields similar results:

> ```
> Searching for zope.interface
> Best match: zope.interface 4.1.1
> zope.interface 4.1.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
>
> Using /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
> Processing dependencies for zope.interface
> Finished processing dependencies for zope.interface
> ```

Since apparently zope is installed on my machine, I'm thinking that the problem could possibly be with the python I've got installed. I installed Python3 with brew earlier this year, and I think I may have messed up the python configuration. Any ideas?

**Update**
The default python that is on mac should work for everything I was trying to do above, I verified this on another mac computer. The problem I was having was that I had corrupted my default python image that came with my mac. By following the post below I was able to create working virtualenv again for my python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do all of your Python work in a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).  If you were to make a fresh virtualenv for your Twisted development, and always activate it before working on it, you would have much tighter control over what gets installed and it would be a lot easier to diagnose problems.  So please make a new virtualenv and `pip install twisted` in it, and then this problem should go away.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however, I'm seriously considering before I setup everything, going back to a clean state. If I reinstall my OSX will it reinstall the mac version of python for me again? I've seriously messed up my configuration by trying to delete python from usr/bin (I can'ti nstall virtualenv without some version of python, and my current version is very dead), so I'd like to revert back to what comes with the OS. Would that work without deleting all my files? Or do I have to a full wipe to fix this.

Comment: I was able to get everything working by using virtualenv as suggested by Glyph. This guide explained the nuts and bolts of what to do and worked perfectly http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: If you have deleted *anything* from `/usr` or `/System/`, then yes, it's time to reinstall your operating system.  *Never* touch those directories on a mac.  (Luckily, on the soon-to-be-released El Capitan, not even root can delete files from those locations.)

Comment: (The exception is `/usr/local`, of course. That one is fine; it's for you, not the operating system.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I did delete those things, and did it on El Capitan, and reinstalling the OS did help remedy the issue, but I still was getting some strange zlib modules missing, what worked best in the end was using virtualenv and installing the needed dependencies.